# A whole sheet into a pandas dataframe with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

Thanks to pandas, we could read a whole sheet into a data frame with the "read_excel" function.

I would like to use the same method using xlwings. In fact, my Workbook is already open and I don't want to use read_excel function (witch will take too long to execute by the way) but use the power of xlwings to save into a dataframe a whole sheet.

In fact with xlwings we could save a range into a dataframe. That mean I have to known the range size. But I guess there is a better (and quicker!) way to do that, isn't it?

Do you have some ideas to do that?
Thanks a lot!

Edit:
One exemple of one sheet I would like to transfer into a dataframe as read_excel would do it.

```
Name Point  Time    Power   Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4 ##
Test    0   1   10  4   24  144
        2   20  8   48  288
        3   30  12  72  432
        4   40  16  96  576
        5   50  20  120 720
        6   60  24  144 864
        7   70  28  168 1008
        8   80  32  192 1152
        9   90  36  216 1296
        10  100 40  240 1440
        11  110 44  264 1584
        12  120 48  288 1728
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To have a better chance of getting your question answered in a timely manner, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide a minimal example so we can reproduce the problem and try to help you.

Comment: Alright, I will make an example. But it's not really a problem. It's "how could I get easily the information from a sheet and pass them into a dataframe".

Comment: "(which will take too long to execute by the way) "

Do you have an example that shows read_excel is slower than xlwings?

Comment: In fact, I work with multiple Workbook. Prior to the process, I copy all the important data into a unique Workbook. So it's obvious that read_excel will take more time to process between multiple workbook than xlwings between multiple sheets. Therefore, I'll make a real example to present the whole problem !

Comment: What do mean by *Workbook*. An Excel file or a sheet within one Excel file? Put differently: do you have several Excel files to read or multiple sheets per file?

Comment: First, I have several Excel files. I put all the important data into one Excel file with several sheets. And I would like to read each sheet as dataframe (like read_excel function).

Answer (score 21):

You can use built-in [converters](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html) to bring it in one line:

```
df = sht.range('A1').options(pd.DataFrame, 
                             header=1,
                             index=False, 
                             expand='table').value
```

Comment: Exactly as you wrote. But you can do this for tables: tbl.range.options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value

Answer (score 8):

xlwings does provide api to load whole sheet. To do that, use `used_range` api which reads whole used part of the sheet. (Of course we don't want to get unused rows values, do we? ;-))
Anyway here is a snippet code on how to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

workbook = xw.Book('some.xlsx')
sheet1 = workbook.sheets['sheet1'].used_range.value
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet1)
```

That's all.

Answer (score 4):

You can read from multiple sheets with pandas:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('myfile.xls')
df1 = excel_file.parse('Sheet1')
df2 = excel_file.parse('Sheet2')
```

So, just open one file after the other, read from the sheets you want and process the data frames.

Comment: Yes I already do this but I was looking for an other solution.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, I could do something like that :

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

def GetDataFrame(Sheet,N,M):
    wb = xw.Workbook.active()
    Data=xw.Range(Sheet,(1,1),(N,M)).value
    Data=pd.DataFrame(Data)
    Data=Data.dropna(how='all',axis=1)
    Data=Data.dropna(how='all',axis=0)
    return Data
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent more time reading a 20M Excel using pandas.read_excel. But xlwings reads Excel very quickly. I will consider reading with xlwings and converting to a Dataframe. I think I have the same needs as the title owner. Xlwings made some adjustments during the four years. So I made some changes to the code of the first answerer.
`

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

def GetDataFrame(wb_file,Sheets_i,N,M):
    wb = xw.books(wb_file)   #open your workbook
         #Specify the value of the cell of the worksheet
    Data=wb.sheets[Sheets_i].range((1,1),(N,M)).value  
    Data=pd.DataFrame(Data)
    Data=Data.dropna(how='all',axis=1)
    Data=Data.dropna(how='all',axis=0)
    return Data
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I made it myself.
It is a function that converts data in the range of startCol and endCol into Pandas data frames by selecting a specific cell location in the search parameter.
I'm using it classified, so I don't know if it's running well, but I hope it helps.

When I use it, I don't use execlFilePath, sheetName, startCol, endCol, but I use integrated cell_range to specify the range, but if I add these integrated functions, the code will be long, so I pull it out and upload it.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def GetDataFrame(execlFilePath, sheetName, startCol=None, endCol='Z', search='A1'):
    r'''
    execlFilePath : 엑셀 파일 경로
    sheetName : 시트 이름
    startCol : 시작 열
    endCol : 끝 열
    search : 특정 데이터 검색할 cell위치
    '''
    # search cell 행열 위치 분해
    searchCOL, searchROW = re.match(r'([A-Z]+)(\d+)', search).groups()

    # 시작열이 없을 경우
    if not startCol:
        startCol = searchCOL

    workbook = xw.Book(execlFilePath)
    # 시트 선택
    worksheet: xw.main.Sheet = workbook.sheets[sheetName]
    # 마지막 데이터 열번호
    row = worksheet.range(search).end('down').row
    # 데이터 가져오기
    data = worksheet.range(f'{startCol}{searchROW}:{endCol}{row}').value
    # 판다스 데이터프레임으로 변환
    return pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```